# when i echo current session value the previous one vanishes i want it to display also what to do

Tags: php, session

my code is

```
       <form method="post" action="order.php?osid=<?php echo $osid?>">
           <textarea id = "myTextArea"
            rows = "20"
            cols = "50" name="myorder" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;"></textarea>                          
           <p><input name="placeorder" value="PLACE ORDER"></p> 
       </form>
```

and php code is

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_POST['placeorder'])){
        $_SESSION['myorder']= $_POST['myorder'];
     ?>
```

and i get this session value in another page as:

```
   <?php

       include 'dbconnect.php';
       session_start();
       echo $_SESSION['myorder'];
   ?>
```

when i enter the new value in text area my previous one get replaced but i want to print all my session values without replacing them how to do it

Comment: Not totally sure I understand what you are asking, but you could try `$_SESSION['myorder'][] = $_POST['myorder'];` so now you have an array of values that that session variable has contained

Answer (score 0):

Make the session variable an array

So each time you capture one, it adds to the array

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['placeorder'])){
    $_SESSION['myorder'][] = $_POST['myorder'];
    . . .
}
?>
```

Then process it like

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION['myorder'] as $order) {
    echo $order;
}
?>
```